# asyncio.sleep() - how to use it?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Can anyone help me out, I'm trying to get the program to pause if the condition is met. But as of now, its not sleeping at all. And I can't wrap my head around why. Im completely new to asyncio

time.sleep() doesnt really work either, so I would prefer to use asyncio. Thanks alot!

```
from python_graphql_client import GraphqlClient
import asyncio
import os
import requests

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def print_handle(data):
    print(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["timestamp"]+" "+str(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"]))
    tall = (data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"])
    if tall >= 1000:
        print("OK")
        # schedule async task from sync code
        asyncio.create_task(send_push_notification(data))
        print("msg sent")
        asyncio.create_task(sleep())
        
        

client = GraphqlClient(endpoint="wss://api.tibber.com/v1-beta/gql/subscriptions")

query = """
subscription{
  liveMeasurement(homeId:"fd73a8a6ca"){
    timestamp
    power
    
  }
}
"""

query2 = """
mutation{
  sendPushNotification(input: {
    title: "Advarsel! Høyt forbruk",
    message: "Du bruker 8kw eller mer",
    screenToOpen: CONSUMPTION
  }){
    successful
    pushedToNumberOfDevices
  }
}
"""
async def sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def send_push_notification(data):
    #maybe update your query with the received data here
    await client.execute_async(query=query2,headers={'Authorization': "2bTCaFx74"}) 
    

async def main():
    await client.subscribe(query=query, headers={'Authorization': "2bTCaFxDiYdHlxBSt074"}, handle=print_handle)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Please, try to change `asyncio.create_task(sleep())` to `await sleep()` and share your results

Comment: In addition I advise to rename `async def sleep()` to `async def asleep_ten_sec()`, since there  is `sleep` in `time` and `asyncio` modules which can lead to unexpected errors

Comment: Your main problem is that you’re mixing asyncio and non-asyncio. You create a task that sleeps, but, because you do it in synchronous code, you can’t wait for it to complete. That’s why it doesn’t appear to be working. Why doesn’t `time.sleep` work?

Comment: tried renaming, didnt work. can't change to await sleep() since def print_handle(data) is not a async method. 

time.sleep doesnt let me send notifications through def send_push_notifications(), as in; the code runs fine without any errors, but no notifications get sent to my phone..

Comment: I think first of all you should step back and think about what you are trying to achieve. I guess your application won't stop sending you notifactions once your threshold is passed, could that be? You don't want to pause your program but simply your notifications?

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword by going to that endpoint I get information about my energy consumption every second. Once I'm using above a certain treshold of kW-usage (effect) I want to send myself an notification. But I dont want to get spammed by shittons of messages if I dont lower my energy usage. Therefor I would like everything to pause for n amount of minutes, then continue getting the energy-consumption through the API endpoint, and repeat.

Comment: I think your comment would have been the better question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to reduce the number of messages being sent, is to define a minimum interval in which no notification is sent while the value is still over the threshold.

```
import time


last_notification_timestamp = 0
NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL = 5 * 60  # 5 min

def print_handle(data):
    global last_notification_timestamp
    print(
        data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["timestamp"]
        + " "
        + str(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"])
    )
    tall = data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"]
    current_time = time.time()
    if (
        tall >= 1000
        and current_time - NOTIFICATION_INTERVAL > last_notification_timestamp
    ):
        print("OK")
        # schedule async task from sync code
        asyncio.create_task(send_push_notification(data))
        last_notification_timestamp = current_time
        print("msg sent")
```

The timestamp of the last message sent needs to be stored somewhere, so we'll define a variable in the global scope to hold it and use the `global` keyword within `print_handle()` to be able to write to it from within the function. In the function we will then check, if the value is above the threshold and enough time passed after the last message. This way you will still keep your subscription alive as well as limit the number of notifications you receive. This is simple enough but probably you will soon want to extend the range of what you want to do with your received data. Just keep in mind that `print_handle()` is a sync callback and should be as short as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to observe broadcasts of some data, and react to those broadcasts, keeping the right to pause those reactions. Something like:

```
async def monitor(read_broadcast):
    while True:
        data = await read_broadcast()
        print(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["timestamp"]+" "+str(data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"]))
        tall = (data["data"]["liveMeasurement"]["power"])
        if tall >= 1000:
            print("OK")
            await send_push_notification(data)
            print("msg sent")
            # sleep for a while before sending another one
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

To implement `read_broadcast`, we can use a "future":

```
# client, query, query2, send_push_notification defined as before

async def main():
    broadcast_fut = None
    def update_broadcast_fut(_fut=None):
        nonlocal broadcast_fut
        broadcast_fut = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()
        broadcast_fut.add_done_callback(update_broadcast_fut)
    update_broadcast_fut()

    def read_broadcast():
        return broadcast_fut

    asyncio.create_task(monitor(read_broadcast))
    await client.subscribe(
        query=query, headers={'Authorization': "2bTCaFxDiYdHlxBSt074"},
        handle=lambda data: broadcast_fut.set_result(data),
    )
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

Note that I haven't tested the above code, so there could be typos.